# Using LINQ to convert array object[,] to array

Tags: c#, performance, linq, saprfc

I have information from external system that always return to me in the following format:

[image: SAP data]

I am required to convert this information from object[,] to an Array split on "|".
I'm been using LINQ in VB to get this information:

```
Dim vSAPdataTemp(,) As Object = Local_SAPtableData.Data

Dim vLinq = From TempResult In vSAPdataTemp
            Select Value = Array.ConvertAll(TempResult.ToString.Split(RFC_DelimiterChar),
                                    Function(vVal) CObj(vVal.ToString.Trim))

Dim vNewSAPdata() As Object = vLinq.ToArray
```

But now I'm moving to C# and I'm stuck with the following error:

[image: LINQ ERROR]

When using this code:

```
var vSAPdataTemp = Local_SAPtableData.Data;

Local_SAPtableData.FreeTable();
fw.gcCleaner();
Local_SAPtableData = null;

var vLinq = (from TempResult in (vSAPdataTemp as Object[,])
                       select string strValue = Array.ConvertAll(TempResult.Split(stcVariables.strSapRfcDelimiterChar), 
                           vVal => (vVal as object).ToString().Trim()));

var vNewSAPdata = vLinq.ToArray<string>();
```

What (if any) workaround exists for this issue?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes sr.

Comment: Just so you know, its LINQ, not LINK (in your title) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcinJuraszek for the answer to my problem. I only want to post the resolution of my specific case:

```
var vSAPdataTemp = Local_SAPtableData.Data;

string[][] vLinq = (vSAPdataTemp as Object[,]).Cast<string>()
                .Select(str => str.Split(stcVariables.strSapRfcDelimiterChar)
                .Select(stra => stra.Trim()).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You most likely have to use `Cast` call:

```
from TempResult in (vSAPdataTemp as object[,]).Cast<object>()
(...)
```

That's because `object[,]` implements non-generic `IEnumerable` which doesn't work well with LINQ. (I have no clue why it works in VB.NET to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
var items = new List<string>();

foreach (var vSAPdata in vSAPdataTemp)
{
    items.AddRange(vSAPdata.ToString().Split('|'));
}
```

**Update**

Testing done with 5 million records...

```
var maxElements = 5000000;
var vSAPdataTemp = new Object[maxElements, 1];

for (int i = 0; i < maxElements; i++)
{
    vSAPdataTemp[i, 0] = string.Format("{0}first|{0}second|{0}third", i);
}

var items = new List<string>();

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

foreach (var vSAPdata in vSAPdataTemp)
{
    items.AddRange(vSAPdata.ToString().Split('|'));
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

Result:

> Elapsed: 00:00:06.25855573

Comment: Thanks for your response; but sometime I have more than 500,000 records. Do a cycle is not an option.

Comment: I tested the above with 5 million records, and it ran in 6.2 seconds...what am I missing?